# Git / GitHub: How to get new local repo into empty remote repo

Tags: git, github

I know this is a newbie question and I have spent hours trying to figure out how to do this on my own, but it's extremely confusing to wrap my brain around, so I'm hoping I can get a little perspective to better orient myself. Honestly, I feel as though I've read the same articles on 20 different websites and understand this even less than before.

I've set up an empty remote repo on GitHub and the branch is the default "main."

I'm using Laravel Forge, so I've connected that to the repo/main and it seems to connect fine.

I have initialized a local repo with my new Laravel project.

Goal: I want to upload (push & pull, I guess?) my local repo to my main repo. When I try to do  "git push origin main" and "git pull main" I get an error:

[image: my git error]

I am clearly not understanding this process and as I read more articles I get more and more confused. Is there a way to simply upload this to my remote repository? This seems so convoluted for such a simple task.

I'm ready to get roasted for not understanding this or have comments like "duplicate," but I really have done a lot of reading and searching, so a little mercy would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you forgot *origin* in the git pull

Comment: I think that's correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this for the past week, I've figured out what I was looking for.

**⚠️ Here is how to push a local repo into an empty GitHub repo**

First, connect your local repo to your remote repo:

```
git remote add origin {remote repository url}

// url format: https://github.com/{GitHub name}/{repository name}.git
```

Next type these commands:

```
git pull      
git add .
git commit -m "{your commit message}"
```

And now for the magic ✨

```
git push -f --set-upstream origin {branch name}
```

This creates an upstream for your local branch, which allows `git push` to work as one might expect. After this, your normal git workflow will work.

Answer (score 1):

`git pull --rebase`

then `git push`

in future, either clone from git then create your begin working, or create on github via pushing rather than creating local + git separately.

Comment: Thank you. I will attempt to do it this way next time!